# How do I count the number of unique pairs in Postgres 9.6?

Tags: postgresql

I want to calculate the number of unique pairs. I am trying the query:

```
select count(distinct a, b) from t
```

But it gives the error:

```
ERROR:  function count(integer, integer) does not exist
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for tuples is (a, b). thus your query should be

```
select count (distinct (a, b)) ab_count from t
```